# Devise - can I bypass timeout check?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise, session-timeout

I'm using Devise in my Rails 3 application. I want to suppress the "session timeout" check for certain functions (urls). Is there a setting that should do that?

In general, any function that does not require authentication should not be subject to timeout (since, in effect, no session is required).

Likewise, when I send a link to a user via email, I don't want that link to be blocked by a session timeout error.

Finally -- obviously -- the sign in and sign out functions should never fail due to a session timeout error.

Our app now has all of these symptoms. Is there a "skip_before_filter" missing?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:**  Scenario details

(1) User is in session, then closes their browser. Later, they open the browser to the sign-in page and sign in. After authentication, they get a "Session Timeout" error message and are returned to the sign in page!!

I want to ignore any "Session Timeout" error *if the user is signing in*.

(2) User is in session, but beyond the timeout period. They click on a link in an email, which takes them into our application. The application throws a "Session Timeout" error message and takes them to the sign in page instead of the link destination. (If they then click on the link in the email again [no session in play], the application proceeds to process the link, without error.)

I want to ignore any "Session Timeout" error *if the user is following a link containing a valid (single-use) token* that they received by email.

(3) User is in session, but idle beyond the timeout period. They click on the "Sign out" link on the web page. The application terminates the session, returns to the sign in page, but shows a "Session Timeout" error message.

I want to ignore any "Session Timeout" error *if the user is signing out*.

(4) User is in session, but idle beyond the timeout period. They go to a function that does not require authentication (e.g., help page, info display, etc.). The application throws a "Session Timeout" error and terminates the session. They try to go to that function again and proceed without interruption.

I don't want "Session Timeout" error to *interrupt navigation to a page that does not require authentication*.

All of these functions are tagged as exempt from the *authenticate user* before_filter. However, the Session Timeout checks are still applied.

How can I prevent session timeout errors for certain functions/methods?

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise (...), :timeoutable

  def timeout_in
    if self.admin? 
      1.year
    else
      2.days
    end
  end
end
```

If there is a session timeout, obviously your users will get redirected to signin page. And you should use `before_filter :authenticate_user!` for all the methods that requires authentication.

As for your email, I guess you can use tokens

Comment: I edited the question to add specific scenarios where the session timeout should not be triggered. Does this help explain my problem better? The email links are typically tokens (such as registration confirmation or email change confirmation).

Thanks